# iOS mobile: scrolling in iFrame within scroll-able parent

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, mobile-safari

I'm experiencing an issue in mobile iOS safari where scrolling in a div that contains an iFrame is impossible when dragging inside the iFrame itself:

```css
#outside{
height: 400px;
width: 200px;
background: blue;
overflow: scroll;
}

.space{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

iframe{
height: 1000px;
width: 200px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
The green section is the iFrame.... Scrolling on the green section in iOS mobile is the issue

<div id="outside">
<div class="space"></div>
<iframe>

</iframe>
<div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

So, when dragging on the iFrame, since it has no scroll, it should scroll the parent, but instead, the whole page is scrolled.

Any known workarounds for this bug? It is already working on Android.

Comment: link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hpo2dg6d/1/

Comment: Adding `pointer-events: none;` to the iFrame element fixes the issue, but this isn't an option, because the iFrame contains links that need to work correctly. :P

Comment: Here is a recent article from Chris Coyier that I found interesting: https://blog.codepen.io/2017/12/01/stupid-iframes-stupid-ios/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your `<iframe>`s in wrappers with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

```css
.iContainer {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```css
#outside {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.space {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

iframe {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  display:block;
}

iContainer {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
The green section is the iFrame.... Scrolling on the green section in iOS mobile is the issue

<div id="outside">
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="iContainer">
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

***Special note:*** Using this in conjunction with `position:relative` on `<body>` causes IoS devices to sometimes block the scroll. Letting it fully revert from it's "bounce" fixes it, but it still feels wrong and buggy.
So make sure you don't have any set `position` on your `<body>` or `<html>`. Took me a bit to debug this quite recently.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm getting a lot closer to solving the problem. I'll accept your answer since it answers the original question completely. However, I didn't mention that the containing div is actually a Bootstrap Modal, which seems to add further complications: https://jsfiddle.net/hpo2dg6d/7/

Comment: according to several people in this thread: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14839 adding the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` is not compatible with bootstrap modals :(

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to scroll a modal, containing an `<iframe>` on all devices in the next decade. We may have walked the Moon, but there are limits to what mankind can do. And the above is one of them. It boils down to all browsers respecting web standards. And that won't happen too soon, imho.

Comment: lol - Actually, it works in every browser outside of mobile iOS browsers currently. And on iOS mobile, it works if I have `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;` on the container and `pointer-events: none;` on the iFrame, but this solution won't work for me because the iFrame contains variable content that often has links that need to work. :P I'll keep looking at possible solutions. Your answer helped me understand some of the quirky behavior of iOS mobile browsers.